# getActiveCell always returns A1

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the new Google Sheets API and any every time I try to get the active cell, it just returns cell A1 in the first sheet, no matter what. Here's my code:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = s.getActiveSheet();
var result = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
```

Seems like a Google bug...

Comment: It's not a bug. Use it with onEdit(), and try to edit any cell, you will get your answer.

Comment: Make sure you don't call `ss.activate()` anywhere (esp. if you copy/pasted the code), because that will reset the active cell to (1, 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently working perfectly for me. If I highlight a cell in the active sheet and run your code, the value in the cell is logged for me.