# I always get the same cell when using getActiveCell()?

Tags: google-apps-script

Why I always get the same result using this code first 3 lines:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1cUmeVEGgKnPcWdUyd55weiMUA4Pn5oXyzLK4ef6YLK5");
  var sheetform = ss.getSheetByName("sheet");
  var indexColumn = sheetform.getActiveCell().getColumn();
```

It always return the same cell (C3) even when I click on another cell in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not currently on the active spreadsheet, (or your script is running without being tied to a spreadsheet), it will always return a fixed value, which is the expected behaviour. ([getActiveCell always returns A1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747477/getactivecell-always-returns-a1)). However, it should actually return "A1" and not "D3". I don't know what the issue there is. But it looks like you're loading an arbitrary sheet, so the behaviour is on expected lines (except that the cell returned should have been A1).